# Libre Office5 Crashes in Ubuntu16.04 whenever a file in ODM is updated

Tags: libreoffice

I have upgraded my OS (from Ubuntu 14.04LTS)to Ubuntu16.04LTS just two days ago. Default Libre Office Version: 5.1.4.2 Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1 is hanging and crashing in a minute (without offering to produce any crash report-) whenever a ODM is updated (Navigator->choose a file->update). If an option to 'update all' is chosen, the system hangs indefinitely.  I am having to save up the document/master and open it all over again all the time to circumvent the problem. Libre office re-opens the document fine, but only after 'recovering' for a considerable length of time.
Is this a memory allocation issue? Am I missing anything simple here?